# Impossible to ship .aar with dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to create an Android library called MyLib.

The library depends on several other libraries and modules: A, B and C.

It seems that when my MyLib.aar is created that A, B and C are not included.

When I integrate my MyLib.aar in to an app I must set A, B and C as dependencies in the app's build.gradle. But I already set them as dependencies in the MyLib library project.

Is this the correct behavior?

Is there any way to package A, B and C with MyLib so that an app that depends on MyLib will not need to explicitly declare A, B and C as dependencies?

Comment: "When I integrate my MyLib.aar in to an app" -- how are you doing this? If you are referencing the AAR as an artifact, the POM should contain the dependency information, to allow consumers of the AAR to know what dependencies (and versions) your library needs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am running the 'assemble' gradle command. This produces a .aar file in my library's app/build/outputs/aar directory. I copy the .aar file and paste it in my app project's app/libs directory and reference the .aar as a dependency in the app/build.gradle file.

Comment: I would recommend that you switch to using a Maven-style repository (even if it is just `mavenLocal()`), so that you can use POM files to express your dependencies. There is nothing in the toolchain to merge AAR files, as you seem to be seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you saying that if I were to use a maven repo that I would be able to achieve my goal of outputing a single .aar that includes dependencies? Or will a maven repo just provide the dependencies for my app project when it's built?

Comment: A Maven module describes its dependencies via a `pom.xml` file. When a build tool such as Gradle or Maven resolves the module, it will also resolve its dependencies. This is called *transitive dependency resolution*, and is preferable over embedding dependencies in most cases. (For AARs, embedding doesn't even seem to be an option.)

Comment: "Or will a maven repo just provide the dependencies for my app project when it's built?" -- this.

Comment: @CommonsWare So if I want to distribute MyLib to other developers and have them be able to resolve the dependencies in their build environments, then it sounds like a solution would be to create a public Maven repo holding the dependencies of MyLib and then the dev using the library would be able to resolve all dependencies. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser actually yes you can embed other libs within an aar but I won't tell you how because I strongly discourage the use of that feature. It is preferable to use transitive dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I want to distribute MyLib to other developers and have them be able to resolve the dependencies in their build environments, then it sounds like a solution would be to create a public Maven repo holding the dependencies of MyLib and then the dev using the library would be able to resolve all dependencies. Am I understanding that correctly?

Generally speaking, yes.

The AAR itself, and its POM file, would be hosted by a repository, one that is visible to whatever developers need the AAR. That could be an in-house repository for a team, all the way up to something like Maven Central.

The dependencies of the AAR will then fall (hopefully) into two camps:

1. Those that are already publicly-visible dependencies (e.g., out on Maven Central), which consumers of your AAR/POM will be able to pull down
2. Those that are your own code, which you would then treat like the AAR itself, putting the dependency and its POM in the repo, so others can get at it when they consume the primary AAR from the repo